# How to convert a html form into a url

Tags: forms, url

I am creating buttons that send the customer to a hosted payment system. In this case an authorize.net Simple Checkout button in test mode.

```
<form name="PrePage" method = "post" action = "https://Simplecheckout.authorize.net/payment/CatalogPayment.aspx"> <input type = "hidden" name = "LinkId" value ="8a40541d-2f0f-4bfe-a1e8-397292f5dee5" /> <input type = "image" src ="//content.authorize.net/images/buy-now-gold.gif" /> </form>
```

My attempt to get the form inputs into the url are following:

```
https://Simplecheckout.authorize.net/payment/CatalogPayment.aspx/?LinkId=8a40541d%2D2f0f%2D4bfe%2Da1e8%2D3d397292f5dee5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The diffence is that you are using the GET method instead of POST.
When you include data in your query string (things after the ? in the URL) you are using the GET method.
If you have a form you can specify to use the POST (as it is in your code example also). In this set up the data is transferred a different way. Not in the query string.

see: [HTTP - Post and Get](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Maybe your server is not handling, only the POST method, so your GET request won't work.